How do you travel between the Cape Verde Islands in November 2024?
We'll be in Cape Verde in November flying in and out of Praia and wanted to visit a few islands if possible. However I have hard time figuring out local transportation.
It looks like the main options are flying or taking a ferry. Flights are plentiful in October but for some strange reasons everything seems to stop on Oct 28. Apparently the only flight still going in November is a once-a-week flight from Praia to Sao Vicente. I tried multiple search engines and directly the airline's website and they all show the same picture.
Below are available flights from Praia to the other larger airports (Sal, Boa Vista and Sao Vicente). There is nothing at all to the smaller airport. It looks like air traffic simply just stops.

From what I've read the ferry is rather unreliable (often delayed and/or cancelled) and the schedule is rather sparse (other than between Sao Vicente and Santa Antao). Even the relatively short hop from Santiago to Maio (< 2 hours) is only served 3 times a week. If the Sunday ferry is cancelled, your stuck on Maio until the next Wednesday, which isn't great if you have a flight to catch.
What's the best way to transfer between the islands in November specifically if you have a hard constraint on "must make my return flight on 11/27 1:23pm". Am I missing something obvious here?

Maybe the website and/or airline only allows you to book 3 months in advance?

Domestic aviation in Cabo Verde is in a bit of flux at the moment. The former main carrier BestFly seems to have ceased operations; the international carrier Cabo Verde Airlines is boosting its domestic capacity; and the government has promised to stabilize the situation by the end of the year. I think the answer may be that nobody yet knows what things will look like in November.

@mlc That seems like a great answer (for now), do you mind posting it as such?

I'm aware that BestFly ceased operation in April but since then Capo Verde airline has covered some domestic traffic.  I was wondering whether this is just a timing issue (3 months) or whether they will stop for good in which case domestic travel will pretty much come to a stand still
